# Can't connect to wifi linux mint

Tags: wifi

`inxi -Fxxz` for my laptop:

```
System:
  Host: mal-Aspire-4752 Kernel: 4.15.0-66-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  compiler: gcc v: 7.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.2.4 wm: muffin dm: LightDM 
  Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire 4752 v: V2.10 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: Acer model: Aspire 4752 v: V2.10 serial: <filter> UEFI: Phoenix 
  v: 2.10 date: 08/25/2011 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 12.8 Wh condition: 12.8/48.8 Wh (26%) volts: 12.4/11.1 
  model: Panasonic AS10D51 serial: <filter> status: Full 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Pentium B950 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  arch: Sandy Bridge rev: 7 L1 cache: 64 KiB L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
  L3 cache: 2048 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 bogomips: 8381 
  Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 800/2100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics 
  vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  chip ID: 8086:0106 
  Display: server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile v: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.8 
  compat-v: 3.0 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio 
  vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:1c20 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-66-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter 
  vendor: Foxconn T77H167.00 driver: ath9k v: kernel port: efa0 
  bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 168c:002e 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Broadcom and subsidiaries NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe 
  vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: tg3 v: 3.137 port: efa0 
  bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 14e4:16b5 
  IF: enp3s0f0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-1: enp0s26u1u1 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 15.56 GiB (3.3%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST9500325AS size: 465.76 GiB 
  speed: 3.0 Gb/s serial: <filter> temp: 40 C 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.96 GiB used: 15.55 GiB (3.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 56.0 C mobo: 44.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 205 Uptime: 32m Memory: 3.70 GiB used: 1.30 GiB (35.2%) 
  Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.4.0 alt: 7 Shell: bash 
  v: 4.4.20 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.32
```

root@mal-Aspire-4752:~# `sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up`

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

`rfkill list`:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Already try to unblock but doesn't change anything

`uname -a`:

```
Linux mal-Aspire-4752 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`uname -r`:

```
4.15.0-66-generic
```

Comment: Dude did you read my report, I say I already try to unblock it using rfkill but nothing happened

Comment: mal@mal-Aspire-4752:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
[sudo] password for mal:    
mal@mal-Aspire-4752:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE              SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      acer-wireless  unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth acer-bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0           unblocked   blocked
 4 bluetooth hci0           unblocked unblocked

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nmcli connection show
```

to find all wifi hotspots and:

```
nmcli connection up <wifi-hotspot>
```

to connect to it.

If your wifi list is not up-to-date,try:

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

or use `nmtui` for gui.

Comment: Still can't connect or update it please refer to my edit

Comment: Are nmtui and nmcli connection up also not working?

Comment: Sometimes your device connects to itself. So disconnect it if that's the case and try: nmcli device wifi list

Comment: Still can't connect, doesn't show my hostpot

Comment: silversilva even using nmtui and nmcli I still can't connect to my wifi

Comment: NAME                UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE     
Wired connection 2  c80bb8a5-3a02-3534-8c7c-9df27ab32e8e  ethernet   enp0s29u1u2
Redmi Network       70bdc763-f881-4d24-a34e-aec878260b36  bluetooth  --         
Wi-Fi connection 1  94aeeede-5ca7-4635-9bf4-e5f5d3e97e6d  wifi       --         
Wired connection 1  d7acaac1-be28-3bdb-aa01-ba8d21ac6950  ethernet   --         
vivo 1902 Network   dc474ff2-b375-4cc2-97ce-3132241de6c4  bluetooth  --

Comment: Can you post the output of nmcli connection up <wifi>?